# How to read predefined number of lines from scanner input based on multiple conditions for the input line

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I need to read maximum 10 lines, with each lines having only characters  * and . also with other conditions like begin with * and length 10. the last line that should be read should have a line following it with the word END. I want to know if there is a better way to solve it than below. If I can check all the conditions within the while loop

```
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int countLine = 0;
    String line = "";
    while (countLine < 10) {
        line = keyboard.nextLine();
        countLine++;
        if (line.matches("[*.]+") && !line.equals("END") && line.startsWith("*") && line.length() < 10
               ) {
          // do something
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    keyboard.close();
```

Comment: What is your question and/or issue?

Comment: check "finite state automata"

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is:

1. read the entire document into your application.
2. parse each (row/column) into arrayLists (so the first 10 lines of the document)
3. perform necessary calculations (still in the while loop).